# iterate over list of complex objects in JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, iteration

I build a list of objects to put into a JSON result:

```
Person personA = new Person("nameA", "age");
Person personB = new Person("nameB", "age");
Person personC = new Person("nameC", "age");

List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

cars.add(new Car("Blue", "Small", personA));
cars.add(new Car("Green", "Big", personB));
cars.add(new Car("Red", "Big", personC));
```

and in my JSON result map, I put:

```
result.put("cars", cars);
```

How to iterate over this collection in JavaScript. I need to have access in object's "deep" elements.

```
$.getJSON(window.actionName,{
            someId: someId}, function (ans){

  //I want something like this
  foreach(car in ans.cars){
      car.person.age
  }
});
```

EDIT:

```
result map private Map<String,List<Car>> result = 
        new HashMap<String, List<Car>>();

    result.put("cars", cars);
```

but it seemes that this lists aren't sent to the client. I get this error in Chrome debugger:

```
ReferenceError: value is not defined
... failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**ANSWER:** Error was because I was serializing objects that had hibernante annotations. I created Bean objects that and serialized them and now the serialization (and iteration is working)

Comment: That status code 500 means your server crashed and burned. Nothing to do with your javascript. Check your shell/IDE/terminal output for JAVA errors.

Comment: Yes, it seemes that the prbolem is in serialization of map. It cant serialize Map<String, List<Object>> but it can serialize Map<String, Object>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//...

  for(var i = 0, car; car = ans.cars[i]; ++i){
      alert(car.person.age);
  }
```

Comment: Tried all of answers. I edited the question. When I was sending simple map as Map<String, String> it was working.

Comment: @vale4674 I don't know what you are doing on the server, but the error is with your server code (probably causing the 500 error) and not the javascript.  I would consider looking into your serialization mechanisms, maybe they aren't able to serialize a hashmap?

Comment: but when I had this one: private Map<String,Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();   and when I was putting strings in key and value, serialization went fine. but now it is not. Is it problem in Collection?

Comment: I've put system.out.println() before and after setting the result map and it seemes that error happens in setting the result.

Answer (score 1):

There's the functional style:

```
ans.cars.forEach(function(car) {
  // do something with ‘car’
});
```

This is standard ECMAScript 5.  As you've tagged this “jquery”, you may want to try the jQuery version instead if you don't want to rely on `Array.forEach` to be there:

```
$.each(ans.cars, function(index, car) {
  // do something with ‘car’
});
```

Comment: Tried all of answers. I edited the question. When I was sending simple map as Map<String, String> it was working.